# ROS, Openni and Kinect not working on a new Ubuntu System

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
after updating my laptop to a new one, i am not able to get ROS, Openni and a Kinect back to work.

On the new Laptop(Acer Aspire V-571) and Ubuntu 12.04 64Bit i installed ROS Fuerte(+openni-camera, openni-lauch).

After starting the

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

i tried `rviz` and `image_view` like on the openni_launch website and my own written node, but i get no picture.
it seems like the kinect is publishing no pictures over the nodes, an rostopic echo on the picture topics shows nothing.
The turtlesim nodes from the Tutorials are working and publishing messages over the topics.

`lsusb` shows the 3 (Motor, Audio, Camera) Devices correct.

Things i have already tried(found as possible help on other answers here):

```
using all USB Slots (USB2 and USB3), even an external USB Hub
killall XnSensorServer
rmmod gspca_kinect
a new (old) Ubuntu Installation with 11.10 and ROS Electric
```

I am not sure what i can test next or where the failure comes from, the Kinect Sensor is working with freenect-glview and on the laptop of a colleague with the same installation steps that doesnt work on my laptop.

the output of roswtf in openni_launch shows:

```
sem@semlaptop:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_launch/launch$ roswtf openni.launch 
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
[rospack] Warning: ignoring duplicate cpp tag in export block
[rospack] Warning: ignoring duplicate cpp tag in export block
[rospack] Warning: ignoring duplicate cpp tag in export block
[rospack] Warning: ignoring duplicate cpp tag in export block
[rospack] Warning: ignoring duplicate cpp tag in export block
[rospack] Warning: ignoring duplicate cpp tag in export block
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

Found 1 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following packages have msg/srv-related cflags exports that are no longer necessary
    <export>
        <cpp cflags="..."
    </export>:
 * dynamic_reconfigure: -I${prefix}/msg/cpp -I${prefix}/srv/cpp


Found 1 error(s).

ERROR The following packages have rpath issues in manifest.xml:
 * openni_launch: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * rosconsole: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * stereo_msgs: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * nodelet_topic_tools: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * depth_image_proc: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * pcl_ros: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * image_proc: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * roscpp: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * roslib: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * rostest: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * pcl: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * camera_calibration_parsers: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * tf: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * nodelet: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * image_geometry: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * message_filters: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * sensor_msgs: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * std_msgs: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * image_transport: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * opencv2: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * openni_camera: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * cv_bridge: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * dynamic_reconfigure: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * bondcpp: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * pluginlib: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * camera_info_manager: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * geometry_msgs: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * rosbag: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"
 * bond: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"

================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
... done running graph rules
running tf checks, this will take a second...
... tf checks complete

Online checks summary:

Found 20 error(s).

ERROR Communication with [/camera/depth/metric] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/camera/driver] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/camera/ir/rectify_ir] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/camera/depth_registered/metric_rect] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/camera/register_depth_rgb] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/camera/depth/metric_rect] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/camera/depth/rectify_depth] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/rosout] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/camera/rgb/rectify_mono] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/camera/rgb/rectify_color] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/camera_nodelet_manager] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/camera/depth_registered/metric] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/camera_base_link3] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/camera/points_xyzrgb_depth_rgb] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/camera/disparity_depth] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/camera/depth/points] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/camera/disparity_depth_registered] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/camera/rgb/debayer] raised an error: 
ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:
 * /camera/depth/points->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /camera/depth/rectify_depth->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /camera/disparity_depth_registered->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /camera/driver->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /camera/depth/metric_rect->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /camera/depth_registered/metric_rect->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /camera/depth_registered/metric->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /camera_nodelet_manager->/camera_nodelet_manager (/camera/rgb/image_raw)
 * /camera_base_link3->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /camera/depth/metric->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /camera/register_depth_rgb->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /camera/points_xyzrgb_depth_rgb->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /camera_nodelet_manager->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /camera/rgb/rectify_color->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /camera/disparity_depth->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /camera/ir/rectify_ir->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /camera/rgb/rectify_mono->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /camera/rgb/debayer->/rosout (/rosout)
 * /camera_base_link3->/camera_nodelet_manager (/tf)
```

but i am not sure how to interprete this or which output/logfile could be more usefull.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44632/ros,-openni-and-kinect-not-working-on-a-new-ubuntu-system/) by [sem](https://answers.ros.org/users/3265/sem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2012-09-26

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sem](https://answers.ros.org/users/3265/sem/) on 2012-09-26**:
i tried it in every combination (Ubuntu 11.10/12.04 - ROS Electric/Fuerte) with the USB2.0/USB3.0 Port and an external USB HUB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Be sure to connect the Kinect to a USB2.0 port not a USB3.0 (I think there is still some issue between Ubuntu and USB3.0).

If your USB is 3.0 take a look at [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/9179/kinect-and-usb-30/)

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2012-12-21**:
This helped me a lot! I didn't even consider that as a possible problem before reading your answer.